# Stored procedure fails, but works correctly when it runs manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2. It was working correctly, but it stopped working (I did not change the code).

It is something difficult to explain, specially because I can not share the stored procedure's code (company's rules). I will try to explain it as much as possible.

This stored procedure is executed by a software, this software calls two stored procedures. One of the stored procedures works correctly and the another one "fails" (it doesn't do anything and not return any error). Both stored procedures do similar things such as update and insert information, from parameters, in some tables. If I check the software's logs I can see that this software is calling both stored procedures correctly. In fact, the stored procedure does not return any error, it just does not do anything.

When I run this stored procedure manually, I use the same parameters that the software should pass and it works correctly.

I simulated a real case and the software called both stored procedures, one works and the another one did not do anything. Then, I executed the second stored procedure manually with the same parameters and it worked correctly.

In addition, the database's user has enough permission (I guess it, because it was working correctly).

Another important thing is that I have two environments with the same databases. The software calls both stored procedures in both environments. In one of the environments it works correctly and the another environment the software calls both stored procedures, but one of them does not do anything as I have explained here.

Regards and thanks!

Comment: if there is nothing to show, there is nothing to answer.

Comment: Hi Jefry, welcome to Stack Overflow. Typically you won't get an answer unless your question is specific enough. You could create a short stored procedure that reproduces the problem and show us how you call it and we could help. Otherwise, you'll have to fire up a SQL Trace and run it while your application calls the procedures - you'll be able to see if it is being called as expected.

Comment: Working when you run it, not working when the software calls it...often points to a variable not being passed correctly to the stored proc (wrong data type?...trailing or leading spaces?).  Without code this is absolute guess work though

Comment: "If I check the software's logs I can see that this software is calling both stored procedures correctly. In fact, the stored procedure does not return any error, it just does not do anything." is probably an assumption that the software is correctly capturing and recording errors. Don't assume - **ever**. You can try a server-side trace or the profiler to gain more insight into what is actually happening.

Comment: @Fenton I run it using Profilers - SQL Trace as you recommended and we found the problem. It was ignoring the code after a print(). We just comment the print() and it is working again. Thank you.  

Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to run the stored proc using Profiler to get exactly what is being sent, it may not be sending what you think it should.

Next check the structure of the two databases for the tables/views referenced, any functions in the procs. Make sure to also check permissions. Script the stored procs in both databases and compare. When database on two servers have an issue like this it is often that the servers are not in sync with the exact code they should have.

Also the data may be different resulting in no data that needs to be acted on by the stored proc in one server.

Comment: Hi, I ran the stored procedure using Profiler as you said and I found with my team that it was ignoring the code after a print(). We just comment the print() and it is working again. We guess it happened because the print was so large, around six thousand characters, but it is also confuse because it was working with that print.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One reason this can happen is the use of temp tables; if they are not available, it may fail, and the scope works differently in a stored procedure than in an interactive session.

Comment: I do not have temp tables, but it is Interesting, I will keep it in mind. I could be useful to know in the future, thanks for your help.